# Suggested ways of reading a text file with inconsistent formatting

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a text file of numbers as a double array and after various methods (usually resulting in an input format exception) I have come to the conclusion that the text file I am trying to read is inconsistent with it's delimiting.

The majority of the text format is in the form "0.000,0.000" so I have been using a Scanner and the useDelimiter(",") to read in each value.

It turns out though (this is a big file of numbers) that some of the formatting is in the form "0.000 0.000" (at the end of a line I presume) which of course produces an input format exception.

This is an open question really, I'm a pretty basic Java programmer so I would just like to see if there are any suggestions/ways of performing this. Is Scanner the correct class to go on this?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Read file as text line-by-line. Then split line into parts:

`String[] parts = line.split("[ ,]");`

Now iterate over the parts and call `Double.parseDouble()` for each part.

Comment: +1: I agree. This is probably the best and simplest way to go.

Comment: It would be much simpler to just set a proper delimiter regex and then continue to read doubles using scanner.nextDouble().

Comment: I have just tried this medthod but I get the exception:

cannot find symbol
symbol  : method split(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String[]
 String[] pixelvaluesparts= pixelvaluesstr.split("[ ,]");

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Scanner allows any Java [Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to function as a delimiter.  You should be able to use any number of delimiters by doing the following:

```
scanner.setDelimiter("[,\\s]");  // Will match commas and whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to comment this in instead of making it a separate answer, but my reputation is too low.  Apologies, Alex.

You mentioned having *two different delimited characters used in different instances*, not a combination of the two as a single delimiter.
You can use the vertical bar as logical OR in a regular expression.

```
scanner.setDelimiter("[,|\\s]"); //Will match commas or whitespace as appropriate
```

line by line:

```
String[] parts = line.split("[,|\\s]");
```